# DJANGO Generic Views: How to use reverse() in get_absolute_url method?

Tags: django, forms, django-generic-views

I'm trying to implement generic editing views as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/):

I started with the CreateView which renders and submits data correctly. However, I am getting an error when I tries to use reverse() to return to the detail view page for the new object.

Here is my Error message:

> NoReverseMatch at /work/clients/create/
>   Reverse for 'ClientDetailView' with arguments '('14',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Here is how I defined get_absolute_url() in my model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('ClientDetailView', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My view is called ClientDetailView. I'm not sure what other information would be helpful.

Here is class ClientDetailView:

```
class ClientDetailView(generic.DetailView):    
    model = Client
    template_name = 'work/client_detail.html'`
```

and here is `url()` from urls.py:

```
url(r'^clients/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='clients_detail'),`
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I had to add the namespace to the reverse() method:

```
return reverse('work:clients_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I would appreciate if someone else could explain why I needed to do this.

Here is the my complete urls.py:
    from django.conf.urls import url

```
from . import views

app_name = 'work'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^work_orders/$', views.WorkOrdersIndexView.as_view(), name='quotes_index'),
    url(r'^work_orders/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.WorkOrdersDetailView.as_view(), name='work_orders_detail'),
    url(r'^quotes/$', views.QuotesIndexView.as_view(), name='quotes_index'),
    url(r'^quotes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.QuotesDetailView.as_view(), name='quotes_detail'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
    url(r'^project/create/$', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project_create'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project_update'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='project_delete'),
    url(r'^clients/$', views.ClientView.as_view(), name='client_index'),
    url(r'^clients/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='clients_detail'),
    url(r'^clients/create/$', views.ClientCreateView.as_view(), name='client_create'),
    url(r'^clients/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.ClientUpdateView.as_view(), name='clients_update'),
    url(r'^clients/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.ClientDeleteView.as_view(), name='clients_delete'),


]
```

Comment: Without your urls.py file(s) it is hard to say. Also it could be that the correction from `reverse('ClientDetailView'...` to `reverse('clients_detail',` would have been enough.

Comment: @tobltobs i added my urls.py file to to the main comment.

Comment: Do you include this file somewhere else, for eg. in a core app? Did you test with `reverse('clients_detail',..`?

Answer (score 0):

actually you are trying to reverse the view, instead of `ClientDetailView`
use url name `clients_detail`